# how to loop through a dictionary as a range

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary with key a start time o a video and its value as end time. each key value pair represents different group. how to check a number exists in range.
eg:

```
dictvid = {146: 209, 509: 539, 0: 145, 304: 320}
```

from 0 to 539 - 210 to 303 and 321 to 508 needs to be in another dictionary
i.e

```
newgroup = {210:303,321:508}
```

Comment: The randomly organized dict keys aren't helping you. If you do one range query it will have linear cost, but K queries will have O(K * N) cost. If you can afford the memory it would be worth your while to read all `(start, end)` tuples and store them in a sorted heap. https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html , to reduce total cost to linear plus O(K * log N). Also, define a `bound` and break any big tuples into several smaller ones so we always have: `end - start < bound`

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a range object from each key-value pair which will give you an O(n) solution (O(n) for iterating over the dictionary + O(1) for the `in` check inside each range object). Note the `+ 1` since range objects are exclusive in the end).

```
print(any(208 in range(start, end + 1) for start, end in dictvid.items()))
print(any(211 in range(start, end + 1) for start, end in dictvid.items()))
```

Outputs

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

dictvid = {146: 209, 509: 539, 0: 145, 304: 320}

i_from = 0
i_to = 539

out = dict()
s = sorted(set(range(i_from, i_to+1)).difference(chain.from_iterable(range(k, v+1) for k, v in dictvid.items())))
for _, g in groupby(enumerate(s), lambda v: v[0]-v[1]):
    l = [*g]
    out[l[0][1]] = l[-1][1]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{210: 303, 321: 508}
```